# Regular expression for lowercase and foreign characters

Tags: php, character, expression, lowercase

I'm trying to find a regular expression allowing all lowercase characters, including some special ones: ŋ, č, đ, á, ž, š, ŧ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For all lower case characters you can have this regex

```
[a-z]*
```

For the special ones in a phrase u can try

```
[a-zA-Z]*č[a-zA-Z]*
```

The regex above is just an example of a foreign case

Of course that if you want to be more complex and experiment with numbers it just needs tweeks.

It's very simple really